# How do I stop PDFs opening in RollerCoaster Tycoon?

Tags: chrome-for-android, default-applications, pdf

I have an unusual problem with Chrome when I try to open PDFs. If I have already downloaded a PDF and try to download it again, I can open it by tapping its name; in the screenshot below, I could tap "pdf.pdf" to open the file.

[image]
The issue is that tapping this link actually opens RollerCoaster Tycoon Classic! If I choose to download again, Chrome redownloads and opens the PDF correctly, so it's not a huge issue, but still an inconvenience.

In Settings, it says that RollerCoaster Tycoon Classic has no defaults, and I am unable to change the "open supported links" setting.

[image]

How do I stop RollerCoaster Tycoon  trying to be a PDF reader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion to install [better open with](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aboutmycode.betteropenwith) app and set the default for opening PDF app worked for OP. Possibly, RCT didn't figure in the options, but setting it to Google Drive fixed the issue